# Can I place my inductors in parallel to make a Flyback?

Tags: inductor, pcb-assembly, flyback

I would like to build a flyback and I've tried simulating my circuit in LTSPICE, in which I coupled a PCH-45X-824 inductor (820µH, 986mA pk) with a 744139 WE-SI inductor (1.124mH, 3A pk).

It works well and provided the output I wanted so I was wondering if I can place the two inductors in parallel to each other on the breadboard/PCB and will it work the same way it did in the simulations?

Thanks!

Edit: I have a 555 pwm to control the switching speed of the mosfet which will control the voltage and duty cycle of the output

Comment: How do you intend on coupling them?

Comment: Expect it to work much more poorly than simulation.

Comment: For a flyback, both inductors should be wound on the same core.

Comment: add the coupling statement from your SPICE file, the K statement, to your post so that you, and we, can see what you're actually simulating. Then you can be advised on how much physical coupling on the PCB is required to match the coupling the simulation uses. Hint, it will probably involve both inductors on the same core, as the other responders have suggested.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Initially I thought by placing them in parallel it will be enough to couple them, just realised that they have to be sharing the same core, my mistake. Thanks

Comment: You mean electrically parallel (both ends connected to the same nets as each other), or geometrically parallel (next to each other facing the same way)?

Answer (score 2):

What does "coupled" mean in your simulation?
Your simulation should have shown ZERO output.
You need a transformer (with both primary and secondary windings on the SAME core) to implement the circuit you have shown.

You must have simulated a transformer. And that is what you will need to implement the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so does it mean that I have to get a ferrite core and calculate the windings for this inductance value to implement this?

Comment: Yes, the inductors have to be magnetically coupled, so they have to share a core as other users have already told you.

Answer (score 0):

Putting two inductors side-by-side (assuming a distance like 1-10 cm between them ) couples these two inductors through the air. **However**, this coupling will be very poor since air itself is a poor magnetic material, and your circuit will not work. In order to increase the coupling you need a ferromagnetic environment. And this can be achieved by winding these two inductors of yours on the same iron core.